# Testing if some function call method on associated object in Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Assume I have some method which call another method on some object:

```
def initialize
  @obj = SomeClass.new
end

def method
  @obj.another_method
end
```

How can I test this with Rspec and `.should_receive`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by passing obj to your class. This technique is called Dependency Injection

http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/09/25/simple-dependency-injection/

```
require "rspec"

class Foo
  def initialize(obj = SomeClass.new)
    @obj = obj
  end

  def method
    @obj.another_method
  end
end

describe Foo do
  describe "#method" do
    subject  { Foo.new(obj) }
    let(:obj){ mock }

    it "delegates to another_method" do
      obj.should_receive(:another_method).and_return("correct result")
      subject.method.should eq "correct result"
    end
  end
end
```

You can also do it like this but it's very bad way of testing class internals

```
require "rspec"

class Foo
  def initialize
    @obj = SomeClass.new
  end

  def method
    @obj.another_method
  end
end

describe Foo do
  describe "#method" do
    it "delegates to another_method" do
      subject.instance_variable_get(:@obj).should_receive(:another_method).and_return("correct result")
      subject.method.should eq "correct result"
    end
  end

  describe "#method" do
    it "delegates to another_method" do
      SomeClass.stub_chain(:new, :another_method).and_return("correct result")
      subject.method.should eq "correct result"
    end
  end

  describe "#method" do
    let(:obj) { mock(another_method: "correct result") }

    it "delegates to another_method" do
      SomeClass.stub(:new).and_return(obj)

      obj.should_receive(:another_method)
      subject.method.should eq "correct result"
    end
  end
end
```

In my code I would use depedency injection and only test output which means no #should_receive at all

```
require "rspec"

class Foo
  attr_reader :obj

  def initialize(obj = Object.new)
    @obj = obj
  end

  def method
    obj.another_method
  end
end

describe Foo do
  describe "#method" do
    subject  { Foo.new(obj)}
    let(:obj){ mock }

    it "delegates to another_method" do
      obj.stub(:another_method).and_return("correct result")
      subject.method.should eq "correct result"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem is, there is no param in initializer:).

Comment: so add parametr with default value :)

Comment: And what if I have module with variable instead of class with initializer?

Comment: @ciembor can you give me example in gist ?

Comment: converter in your gist is example of global variable so this code is kind of broken

Comment: I wouldn't say it's global, it's in MyModule scope.

Answer (score 1):

While the dependency injection provided by the other answer is preferable, given your existing code, you would need to do something like:

```
describe "your class's method" do
  it "should invoke another method" do
    some_mock = double('SomeClass')
    SomeClass.should_receive(:new).and_return(some_mock)
    someMock.should_receive(:another_method).and_return('dummy_value')
    expect(YourClass.new.another_method).to eq('dummy_value')
  end
end
```

where `YourClass` is the class in question.

Update: Added check for returned value with nod to @Lewy

Comment: Because you are not testing output of the method when somebody change implementation like this

https://gist.github.com/lefty313/2df68764ec65d1d83c83

this spec still be passing